# Создание словаря на основе Dictionary<> в C#

Tags: c#, словари

В Java использую собственную карту на основе HashMap() вида:

```
public class MySet extends HashMap<String, Object>
{
    public MySet()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MySet(final int size)
    {
        super(size);
    }

    public MySet(final MySet set)
    {
        super(set);
    }

    public void set(final String key, final int value)
    {
        put(key, value);
    }

    public int getInteger(final String key)
    {
        final Object val = get(key);

        if (val instanceof Number)
            return ((Number) val).intValue();
        if (val instanceof String)
            return Integer.parseInt((String) val);
        if (val instanceof Boolean)
            return (Boolean) val ? 1 : 0;

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("MySet : Integer value required, but found: " + val + " for key: " + key + ".");
    }

    // Остальные методы добавления и чтения по примитивам.
    ...
}
```

В С# ума хватило только на:

```
public class MySet : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public MySet() : base()
    {

    }

    ...
}
```

Подскажите как добавить инициализацию первичного размера словаря (если это возможно в такой модели) и как присвоить сформированный сет в создаваемый?

Comment: да все также, у `Dictionary` есть конструкторы принимающие на вход и число и другой `Dictionary`

Comment: @yolosora в двух моих вопросах не было ни слова о записи и чтении примитивов. Прочтите пожалуйста внимательнее. Если не понятно, то нужно реализовать первые 3 метода присваивания из Java примера.

Comment: так это же конструкторы, а не методы присваивания

Comment: @yolosora да, точно. Извиняюсь. Попутал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MySet : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public MySet()
        : base() { }
    public MySet(int capacity)
        : base(capacity) { }
    public MySet(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        : base(dictionary) { }
    // аналогично с любой другой сигнатурой констрктора
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно было.