# Вернуть Enum или Class из Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, enum, типы, словари

Помогите адаптировать методы для C# из Java (методы используются в расширении базового Dictionary. Тема [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862462/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-dictionary-%D0%B2-c).):

```
public <A> A getObject(final String key, final Class<A> type)
{
    final Object val = get(key);

    if (val == null || !type.isAssignableFrom(val.getClass()))
        return null;

    return (A) val;
}

public <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(final String name, final Class<E> enumClass)
{
    final Object val = get(name);

    if (val != null && enumClass.isInstance(val))
        return (E) val;
    if (val instanceof String)
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, (String) val);

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enum value of type " + enumClass.getName() + "required, but found: " + val + ".");
}
```

Для первого метода я использую следующую реализацию:

```
public object getObject(string key, Type type)
{
    object val = this[key];

    if (val == null || !type.IsAssignableFrom(val.GetType()))
        return null;

    return val;
}
```

Но у неё есть один недостаток - нужно постоянно указывать тип получаемого объекта. Выглядит это так:

```
Version _build = (Version) set.getObject("buildVersion", typeof(Version));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы не просто

```
public T GetObject<T>(string key) where T:class
{
    return this[key] as T;  
}
```

Вызов будет как

```
var build = set.GetObject<Version>("buildVersion");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так проще.